# cannot drop a system-generated sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a system-generated sequence in my Oracle 12c database that I cannot seem to get rid of. Calling "drop sequence" on it gets this error:

> Error code: ORA-32794
>   Description: cannot drop a system-generated sequence
>   Cause: An attempt was made to drop a system-generated sequence.
>   Action: A system-generated sequence, such as one created for an identity column, cannot be dropped.

The sequence was used to generate values for a table's Id column, and the table no longer exists. Usually, I can create and drop such tables and the sequence drops with it. I do not know the statements by which the table was dropped in this instance, but I would really like to remove the stray sequence.

Comment: Which version of 12c are you using?

Comment: It is 12.2, which was the latest at the time several months ago.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should not need to drop an identity column sequence explicitly, as it is associated with the table, and dropping the table with the `purge` option (or dropping normally and emptying the recycle bin) will also drop the sequence.

```
create table test_tbl (id  number generated as identity);

Table created.

select * from user_tab_identity_cols;

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME GENERATION_TYPE SEQUENCE_NAME IDENTITY_OPTIONS
------------------------------ ----------- --------------- ------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST_TBL                       ID          ALWAYS          ISEQ$$_124811 START WITH: 1, INCREMENT BY: 1, MAX_VALUE: 9999999999999999999999999999, MIN_VAL
```

Dropping the table leaves the table and its sequence in the recycle bin:

```
drop table test_tbl;

Table dropped.

select * from user_tab_identity_cols;

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME GENERATION_TYPE SEQUENCE_NAME IDENTITY_OPTIONS
------------------------------ ----------- --------------- ------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BIN$gQ8wv//QTjK+mAGxdffxgQ==$0 ID          ALWAYS          ISEQ$$_124811 START WITH: 1, INCREMENT BY: 1, MAX_VALUE: 9999999999999999999999999999, MIN_VAL
```

Emptying the recycle bin clears it:

```
purge recyclebin;

Recyclebin purged.

select * from user_tab_identity_cols;

no rows selected

select * from user_sequences where sequence_name like 'ISEQ$$%';

no rows selected
```

Comment: *"You should not need to drop an identity column sequence explicitly"* I seem to recall there was an issue with the initial release of 12c R1 whereby dropping a table with an identity column did not drop the system-generated sequence. It was pain because in development we trashed and rebuilt schemas on a frequent basis. But certainly it's no longer an issue in the later releases.

Comment: "purge recyclebin" cleaned them up. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Is there a way to clear the reference without purging the recyclebin? I would avoid to purge a shared resource for all the users, even if it's just a recyclebin

Comment: I also found out that purging the recyclebin requires special privileges. So I'm looking for an alternative solution

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina I didn't think `purge recyclebin` required any special privileges. Which privilege are you missing? But in any case you can purge the table when you drop it using `drop table test_tbl purge;` or if you have already dropped it you can `purge table test_tbl`.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop a table and purge the system-generated sequence with a single drop command by using the purge keyword

```
drop table mytable purge cascade constraints
```